# How does FusedLocationProviderClient.getCurrentLocation work? CancellationToken

Tags: java, android, location, android-gps, fusedlocationproviderclient

I'm trying to request the current location, and if the task goes wrong, call if location is on.

```
private void getCurrentLocation() {
    fusedClient.getCurrentLocation(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, new CancellationToken() {
        @Override
        public boolean isCancellationRequested() {
            return false;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public CancellationToken onCanceledRequested(@NonNull OnTokenCanceledListener onTokenCanceledListener) {
            Log.d("CurrentLocation", "CancelRequest");
            createLocationSettingRequest();
            return null;
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                Log.d("CurrentLocation", location.toString());
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this)
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is code in **onCancelationRequested** executes twice; I tried with CancellationTokenSource but I had same results.

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/CancellationTokenSource#cancel()) only the first call to `cancel()` will have an effect. You can check it by adding `addOnCanceledListener()` which would be called only once.